# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor del label?

Tags: php

Muy buenas.

Tengo un problema en mi página este es mi label:

```
<label type="text"class="INSPECCIONES" id="l1" name="l1">CARROCERIA/CAPOT</label>
```

Deseo obtener el valor del label osea *"carroceria/capot"*.

¿Cómo hago para obtener  "carroceria/capot" y guardarlo en en base de datos?, 
yo estoy usando un archivo `php`.

```
$l1=$_POST["l1"];
```

y después `$l1` lo pongo en la consulta. Pero cuando reviso la base de datos el campo me sale vacío.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido Carlos, te recomiendo hagas el [tour] para que conozcas un poco más acerca del sitio, de igual manera lee [ask] y [mcve] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad, para poder ayudarte inserta el código que llevas y lo que haz intentado, buen día. :D

Comment: Por favor explica mejor tu problema e indícanos el código que estás usando. Así podremos ayudarte mejor. No se entiende nada.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes coger el valor HTML de un label, pero si que puedes añadir en tu formulario un input oculto cuyo valor sea el texto del label:

```
<input type='hidden' name='l1_1' value='CARROCERIA/CAPOT' />
<label type="text"class="INSPECCIONES" id="l1" name="l1">CARROCERIA/CAPOT</label>
```

Despues en el POST de PHP

```
$l1=$_POST["l1_1"];
```